# Phalcon REST - cmoore4/phalcon-rest

Tags: php, rest, backend, phalcon

Good day!
I'm trying to create rest for angular using phalcon - https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest

Hello!
I have similar error https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest/issues/10
But i can't resolve it.

I have database (*.ini)

```
[database]
    dbname = orcl
    username = root
    password = root
```

Service

```
$config = new IniConfig('Database.ini');
$di->set('dbOracle', function () use ($config) {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Oracle(
        array(
            "username" => $config->database->username,
            "password" => $config->database->password,
            "dbname"   => $config->database->name
        )
    );
}, true);
```

In Models folder

```
namespace PhalconRest\Models;
use \PhalconRest\Exceptions\HTTPException;
class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function getSource() {
        return 'Users';
    }
}
```

In controller trying

```
class UsersController extends RESTController {
    protected $allowedFields = array(
        'search' => array('id', 'login'),
        'partials' => array('id', 'login')
    );
    $users = Users::find();
```

And get **502 Bad Gateway** nginx.

error.log

```
*20 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

Please, can you help me?

Comment: How about http://phalcon-rest.redound.org Did you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

See: [HTTP Status Code error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Your vhost configuration might the cause of your problem:

```
fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
```

Change to

```
fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```